# Hand itemssource to custom control derived from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, custom-controls, .net-4.5

I am using wpf in .NET 4.5 and I would like to have a data grid template to embed in other DataTemplates. I use a DataTemplateSelector to display the content of a list of children of a common parent class.

I would just like to change the ItemsSource of my DataGrid, as it has a different property name in each class.

The general Binding of the  in my DataGrid template can have the same bindings, as the list always contains the same class.

Therefore, I created a custom class deriving from DataGrid. In line it works great, but when i use my custom class i do not get any output in the DataGrid.

So how can i make my custom control make to behave like the normal datagrid. I just would like to change the datasource there.

Thanks in advance.

Inline example works fine:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KnotPoints, Converter={StaticResource geoArrayToDataGrid}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Num, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Custom UserControl does not return any content:

```
<DataGrid x:Class="FlexForCFK.CAD.Controls.MultiGeoStruct"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Num, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:**
The custom Control MutliGeoStruct is placed here in the code:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Knot Points" IsExpanded="True">
     <y:MultiGeoStruct ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KnotPoints, Converter={StaticResource geoArrayToDataGrid}}"/>
</TreeViewItem>
```

(y is the namespace of my control)

```
xmlns:y="clr-namespace:FlexForCFK.CAD.Controls"
```

Comment: For your second example (MultiGeoStruct), where do you set its ItemsSource? Please add the code where you set/bind the ItemsSource property of *FlexForCFK.CAD.Controls.MultiGeoStruct* to your question.

Comment: Where is the DataContext set which is being used for the `{Binding Path=KnotPoints,...}` binding on *MultiGeoStruct.ItemsSource*? It looks to me that in your first example the DataContext used for the *DataGrid.ItemsSource* binding was set correctly, whereas in the 2nd example, the binding for *MutliGeoStruct.ItemsSource* seems to work with a wrong DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Not the solution!

Elgonzo is right. I have to set the

```
 DataContext="{Binding}"
```

for my MultiGeoStruct DataGrid.

```
 <y:MultiGeoStruct DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KnotPoints, Converter={StaticResource geoArrayToDataGrid}}"/>
```

That solved the problem. But why is that? In my top TreeView i never set DataContext at all, as I understood it, if you use ItemSource the Collection is directly given to the Items and the DataContext of the parent does not need any defining at all.

So I just set, when my Data is loaded in my TreeView

```
this.ItemsSource = m;
```

and it works just fine.

Thank you very much for your help.

If you know the answer please enlighten me. If I have an explaination I'll update this.

Comment: Somewhere you did set a DataContext. `DataContext={Binding}` tries to pull the value of the *DataContext* property and puts it back into DataContext. However, remember that DataContext inherits its value from the DataContext property of the parent FrameWork element, if it is not set explicitly. So, in reality `DataContext={Binding}` makes it pull the value of the DataContext property of a parent Framework element and puts into into MultiGeoStruct.DataContext. That is in effect the same as not setting MultiGeoStruct.DataContext at all. So, why is this modification makes your code work? (contd.)

Comment: The only reasons i can think about is some trickery in code-behind or some very strange XAML for the TreeView or the XAML surrounding it...

Comment: It does not work. It just fell back to autogeneratecolumns and therefore, the content was displayed. But I found out, that the datacontext is allright, if I put the xaml code for my columns directly in the container of my MultiGeoStruct datagrid (like with a normal one). My custom dg is not using my template I defined in the xaml code of my custom control. That's why nothing is displayed, I guess.

Also, if I set my AutoGenerateCulumns Property to false in my xaml code of MutiGeoStruct.xaml, it is overwritten to the default value, if I insert my Element in my ModelContentViewer.xaml.